# How many functions $f$ from $A$ to $B$ are not injective, not surjective?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a problem specific to discrete mathematics, more exactly: functions.

Let's say, we have two finite non-empty sets: $A$ and $B$. Moreover, we have a function $f$ from $A$ to $B$.
Finally, we denote $|A|$ to be the cardinal of the set $A$, so we might have $|A|=n$ and $|B|=m$.
How many functions $f$ from $A$ to $B$ are not injective, not surjective?

I need a generalized rule for computing the number of not injections, not surjections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:the number of functions from $A$ to $B$ is $n^m$.

Now find the number of functions that are injective **and** surjective.Let's say there are $k$ in number.

Then what you ask is $n^m-k$.

Of course,if $n\neq m$ we have that $k=0$.

Now, if your intention was to ask how many functions are only not injections,just find the number of injections and do the same ask above.

Same for the number of only not surjections.

Comment: You helped me a lot! Thank you. I forgot about the number of functions.

Comment: The number of injections when $n \le m$ is straightforward, but the number of surjections when $n \ge m$ is trickier.